# Save files avoiding duplicate filenames and overwriting

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, file

**So, here's my situation :**

- I've got an application prompting the user to select a folder to save his files
- Now let's say his files are : `a.png`, `b.png`, `c.png`

**What I want is :**

- if file - let's say - `a.png` already exists in the selected folder, **DON'T** overwrite it. Instead create a file with name `a (1).png`. If a file `a (1).png` already exists, then name it like `a (2).png`, and so on - pretty much like OS X does when copy-pasting files with the same name.

This is how I'm currently doing it - but it still doesn't strike me ok :

```
NSString* target = [self getTargetPathForFile:filename path:folder];

NSString* fname = [target lastPathComponent];

while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]])
{
    //NSLog(@"FNAME : %@",fname);

    if ([self str:fname containsString:@")." options:nil])
    {
        NSArray* a = [fname componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
        NSArray* b = [[a objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];

        fname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%d)%@",[a objectAtIndex:0],[[b objectAtIndex:0] intValue]+1,[b objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    else
    {
        fname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (1).%@",[fname stringByDeletingPathExtension],[fname pathExtension]];
    }

    //NSLog(@"Setting filename to :: %@",fname);
}
target = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
```

Any ideas how to go about this? Is there any Cocoa-friendly (or built-in) method for this?

Comment: Is it important what the filenames are?  Why not generate a UUID for each file and keep some sort of index of filename to UUID?

Comment: @trojanfoe I've had this idea about UUIDs, but can it be used (and how?) to name the files as suggested (`a (1).png`, etc)?

Comment: When a new file needs to be saved you generate a UUID and save it (this is guaranteed to avoid any conflict).  You then store the UUID/name the user wants to call the file into an NSDictionary (using UUID string as key) and then save this dictionary to index.plist or something.  When you start the app you load this index and the user can have multiple files with the same name (I don't know if that will suite your needs or not).  The important thing is that the name on the filesystem is unique and you can map a 'real name' back to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not try this one :

```
NSString* fname = [target lastPathComponent];
NSString* fnameNoExt = [fname stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString* extension = [fname pathExtension];

int fileIndex = 1;
while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname]])
{
    //NSLog(@"FNAME : %@",fname);
    fname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d).%@", fnameNoExt, fileIndex, extension];
    //NSLog(@"Setting filename to :: %@",fname);
    fileIndex++;
}
target = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
```

Comment: Much better implementation. Thanks a lot, buddy! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really care about the file names as you explained in one of your comment, and can consider using automatically-generated file names instead, use either [`CFUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html), `NSProcessInfo`, or `mkstemp`.

- Using `CFUUID` to generate a unique identifier `str`:

  ```
  CFUUIDRef uuidref = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef cfstr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidref);
  // If using ARC:
  NSString* filename = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)cfstr;
  // If not using ARC
  NSString* filename = [(NSString*)cfstr autorelease];
  // Then release the CFUUIDRef
  CFRelease(uuidref);
  ```
- Using `NSProcessInfo`

  ```
  NSString* filename = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
  ```
- Using `mkstemp`: see [CocoaWithLove](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html)

Comment: Oh yeah, why is that familiar?